# Format date inside table from database

Tags: powershell, formattable

I'm trying to create a script for querying a database, extract data and put it to an *.csv* file. This is the part of interest of the code:

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
###########################

##PRSENTAZIONE DEI RISULTATI##
$table = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$table.Load($result)
$table | Export-Csv -Path $fileName -Delimiter "|" -NoTypeInformation
```

I have 2 problems:

1. On Windows 2003 PowerShell `-Delimiter` parameter is not present
2. If I delete that parameter the ouput file presents a wrong format date.

   `username, ipaddress, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` (running the same query in Management Studio), `username, ipaddress, "dd/mm/yyyy hh.mm.ss"` (apexes included `;` printing the `$table`).

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you want timestamps in a particular format tell your database that you want timestamps in a particular format. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

Comment: If your CSV is well-formed, you can parse it yourself.  Filter Left, Format Right.  Why are you trying to manually specify a delimiter?